# Joomla admin url under htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla, virtuemart

I've got a site running by Joomla. The /administrator/ path is restricted in robots.txt and the password is asked if i try to open backend at /administrator/
I have a virtuemart shop installed, and the superadmin login/password.
I can log in on the frontend, and edit virtuemart items, but i want to be able to open joomla's admin page as well, and to add some components.
I need some assistance with it, please.

Comment: If the password is asked, and you have the password, why don't you just log in?

Comment: The password is asked by htaccess, and i've got only joomla superadmin password.

Comment: Well, than better find out the password. If you have access to the server, look in the .htaccess, it should show where the password is defined. Usually it's a file called .htpasswd.
If you don't have access to that, contact either the person who set it up or the server administrator.

Comment: I would appreciate the answer to my question. Not the workarounds. I'm logged in as a superadminisrator, and i need to be able to add components on the backend(extplorer, as a matter of fact).

Comment: The answer you're looking for does not exist. You can't install components to the fronted, if the .htaccess protection denies you access to the backend, than you're out of luck.

Comment: You think there's no way going to backend by adding index.php?option=com_config or something like that?

Comment: Do you have root access to the server hosting your website?  The answer is to edit the .htaccess file, but to be honest I'm not sure why access to admin portal would be prevented on a CMS website.  Can you post a screen shot of the page when navigating to /administrator?

Comment: @Brian Bolli here you go: http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/4102/j54d.png I have no access to the server. Otherwise i surely would edit what i need ; ) Thats why i need eXtplorer extension.

Comment: @Ulrikhe Lukoie Well,  I'm sorry to say your options are very limited at this point.  You can either find the person with access to remove password requirement from .htaccess or find another host for your Joomla website.  Anything else would be considered "hacking" as you're trying to circumvent the server administrator's implemented security.